# How do I get the status of the StatusBarItem-Check box

Tags: geotools

I would like to add a checkBox for toggle drawing of a map grid (on/off) as a StatuBar item.
the map grid should be drawn if the checkbox is set and if there has been an update of the mapPane.
How can I see if the checkbox is set or not in my displayGrid() function?
I'm adding the JGridStatusbar item like this:

```
    JMapStatusBar statusBar = new JMapStatusBar();
    statusBar.addItem(new JRendererStatusBarItem(mapPane), false, true);
    statusBar.addItem(new JCoordsStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JExtentStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JCRSStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JScaleStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JGridStatusBarItem(mapPane));
```

My JGridStatusBarItem:

```
private static final String COMPONENT_NAME = "Grid on/off";

        /**
         * Creates a new item to display the map grid of the associated map pane.
         *
         * @param mapPane the map pane
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code mapPane} is {@code null}
         */
        public JGridStatusBarItem(MapPane mapPane) {
            super(COMPONENT_NAME,false);

            if (mapPane == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("mapPane must not be null");
            }
            mapPane.addMapPaneListener(
                    new MapPaneAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDisplayAreaChanged(MapPaneEvent ev) {
                            displayGrid();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to call `isSelected()` on the checkbox component in your draw method. You might also want to fire an event in the `ActionListener` method of the component to let the grid know it needs to change it's state.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I don't know on what component I shall thest isSelected() on, where do I get the checkbox?

Comment: make `new JGridStatusBarItem(mapPane)` into a variable and then check that, or use `statusBar.getItem(5)` but I'd be wary of the magic number,

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I created the variable as you suggested, but I can't test isSelected() on the GridStatusBarItem and I can't find the checkbox component in the GridStatusBarItem or in the popUpMenu (statusBar.getConfigMenu())...

Comment: Is this the best way to do it, it doesn't feel right?               `if(statusBar != null) { JPopupMenu  tmp = statusBar.getConfigMenu(); if (tmp != null) { chkboxGrid = (JCheckBoxMenuItem)tmp.getComponent(4);   if(chkboxGrid.isSelected()) MapView.drawGrid = true; else MapView.drawGrid = false; } }`